# Утилиты для работы с текстом в Windows

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

В Windows есть PowerShell. Программа далеко не простая и возможности у нее не хилые. С PowerShell я вообще никак, лишь по аналогии с Unix/Linux могу работать.

Способен ли PowerShell работать с текстом, как это доступно в Unix/Linux (wc, cat, sort, grep, uniq, paste, diff, sed, awk)?

Comment: https://wiki.soulruins.info/docs/blog/2016/10/powershell_console_editor

Comment: Весьма интересно. Воспользуюсь.

Comment: В нём многое можно сделать, хотя принцип скорее как в Питоне, чем как в shell — гораздо больше писать и на более низком уровне.

Comment: А так, ставьте оболочку Linux (Windows Subsystem for Linux, WSL). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

Comment: Порты всех перечисленных программ, разумеется, существуют и для Windows.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению редактора как такового для powershell нет. Но ! Можно **установить bash для windows** и с привычного нам powershell'a запускать тот же редактор vim , emac , nano просто написав:

**ps> bash -c "vi filename.txt"**

Для установки следуйте гайду: [тык](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10)

Либо просто погуглив как установить bash под вашу винду :)

Отсюда можно немного поколдовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавив строчку выше в profile powershell'а , у нас будет готовая команда **nano** при каждом запуске powershell. Теперь мы легко можем пользоваться редактором :

```
#открыть пустой файловый редактор
ps>nano

#открыть файл readme.txt в текущей папке
ps>nano ./readme.txt
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*(не забывайте только менять знак ".\" на -> "./"):*

Всего наилучшего!